# Can not start start emacs server

Tags: emacs, emacs23

When I run start-server in Emacs I get the following in my *Messages* buffer:

```
 apply: Cannot bind server socket: cannot assign requested address
```

This Emacs binary is available on a bunch of hosts at my site but it only has a problem on one host.  Not sure what the cause is.  Does anybody have an idea about how I can begin to debug this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ they will surely help you

Comment: I don't think emacs server is enough of a server for a question on serverfault.com.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885793/emacs-error-when-calling-server-start) addresses an issue starting emacs server.  At least three of the answers fix that problem.

Comment: You need to give more information: what Emacs version? on what OS? installed how? Do you have the same problem if you skip your `.emacs`?

Comment: @BlackBear: Absolutely not Server Fault. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be the right venue, or [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) if the platform is a unix one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super User is probably a more appropriate venue for this. They tend to deal with OS-related questions as well.

That said, are you absolutely certain that the client isn't already running on the host in question? That would prevent it from binding to the socket... Make sure the user has appropriate permissions to create the socket on that system. Make sure that the socket isn't stuck in some intermediate state (maybe the permissions got set wrong, and now the user can't create a new one). Try deleting the socket if it exists, and let Emacs create a new one.

Comment: I definitely would suspect the problem is caused by another emacs server already running.