# PC Emacs error in startup

Tags: windows, emacs, installation

Following [Installing Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Installing-Emacs.html#Installing-Emacs), I set `HOME` environment variable to a directory (c:), and make a _emacs file in the directory. It has this one line of code `(server-start)`.

When I execute emacs (GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)), I get this error message.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/_emacs':

error: The directory `~/.emacs.d/server' is unsafe
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: At a guess Emacs is complaining because other users have access to the folder.  Try removing Users from the permissions on .emacs.d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Emacs - Error when calling (server-start)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885793/emacs-error-when-calling-server-start) has the answer.

> "The problem is the ownership of the directory ~/.emacs.d/server when
>   you also have “Administrators” rights on your account. Create the
>   directory ~/.emacs.d/server and set the owner of this directory to
>   your login name and the problem is gone.

Comment: Also consider moving `c:/_emacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and adding `(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/custom-variables.el")` to keep emacs related configurations in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on Windows 7 (or perhaps Vista)? At some point after XP, Windows decided that putting things in c:\ is a no-no. I guess for security reasons. If you don't set a home environment variable, then emacs will look for your .emacs in c:\users\yourname\appdata\roaming (or something like that - Win 7 machine w/emacs is at work, can't check exactly). You can also create your .emacs.d directory there too if you want.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, the message is not clear enough. Probably, Emacs should not simply barf this way. In any case, my advice would be to use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to let the Emacs developers know about this. Hopefully they will address the problem one way or another -- at least provide a more helpful message to users.