# How to recover from LispCabinet error "the server directory is unsafe"?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I installed LispCabinet and after the first start it tells me:

server-ensure-safe-dir: The directory `c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/ApplicationData/.emacs.d/server' is unsafe

What does this mean, how did it come, is it dangerous and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a windows account with administrator permissions. The server directory in emacs.d was owned by the group "Administrators". I changed the ownership from the user group "Administrators" to be owned by the username I am currently working with (which is "Administrator") and the error message went away.

This solution is quite similar to the one given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944197/1312456