# spacemacs warning: directory is unsafe

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I received this error whenever I start spacemacs

```
error: The directory `/var/folders/2g/9ndwhk353n97d5vgcqdpsz580000gr/T//emacs504' is unsafe
```

It seems like no one has had this problem before.
It is probably due to I did `chflag` on some directory sometime ago, but I couldn't remember what I did exactly..

I'm on Mac and my spacemacs is in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Not seen that specific error before, but Emacs tends to complain about directories being 'unsafe' when someone other than the user currently running Emacs owns or has access to the directory.

See this other Stackoverflow question for a Windows example:

[Emacs - Error when calling (server-start)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885793/emacs-error-when-calling-server-start))

In your case, I would just delete the `emacs504` folder, as emacs probably will recreate it with the correct perms since it's in `/var/`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for `/tmp/emacs...` directory for using Spacemacs based on Cgywin Emacs 26.1. Just removing the directory and then restart of emacs did not solve the problem for me. But simply changing the access rights for the directory using `chmod g-rwx /tmp/emacs...` did the job.